# Testing the iframe content

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, iframe, rspec

I'm running ruby on rails project and I'm wondering is there a way to test the iframe content.

This is the first time I test something like this so I don't know how to start or which tools to use.

I'm embedding other website part in some part of my website, and so I want to make sure that the iframe returns 200 or some other success indicator, otherwise I would display some kind of error.

I use Jasmine, rspec, selenium etc. Is there anything that accomplish this?

Comment: Just start your rails server? Make sure the server that the iframe is hosted on (if it's not the same one) is also running, and just open your browser. You can also use a web debugging proxy such as charles to see response headers and other useful info

Comment: @user2879041 but that won't give me information at the time I make the call. At that very second the other website could crash and my users would be left with no content or broken content

Comment: So the iframe is another website altogether, and not your own content, right?

Comment: If it is another domain, there is really nothing you can do on the clientside.

Comment: ^ exactly, pretty much. if it's your own website though on another domain you could try to leverage the html5 messaging api and if you get a response then you know it's okay (200). and if no response you could remove the iframe and replace it with an image or div saying unavailable.

Comment: @user2879041 can you add that as an answer with messaging api example. I'm not sure what you mean thanks

Comment: added it as an answer for you @GandalfStormCrow

Answer (score 0):

On your iframe'd website you do something like

```
window.onload = function(){
   parent.postMessage(message, url); 
}
```

and on your website that hosts the iframe you have an event listener on the iframe for a message. check this link out http://javascript.info/tutorial/cross-window-messaging-with-postmessage

Comment: I don't want to put code on the website I'm including in. There is no need to do that

Comment: then you are out of luck. cross domain policy won't allow for the capabilities you want